# Regarding the @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Tags: c#, redirect, antiforgerytoken

So I was wondering how important the antiForegryToken is, because it is causing some problems for me.

I have a class where i look if the user is in role "PremiumAnvändare" (it's PremiumUser in swedish) and if not I redirect them to "rolenotfound".

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {

        if (User.IsInRole("PremiumAnvändare"))  
        {
            ViewBag.SammanhangsID = new SelectList(db.Sammanhangs, "SammanhangsID", "Namn");
            return View();


        }
        Response.Redirect("rolenotfound");
        return View();
    }
```

But when the user is redirected to rolenotfound i get the error

> An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> The server can not add a header after HTTP headers have been sent.

This is resolved by deleting the @Html.AntiForgeryToken()[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is it okay to remove the token? I resarched it a bit and I understand it is to defend against cross site attacks but I don't believe this will be a problem since we are making a mobile app. But please correct me and teach me so I can make this right.

Comment: That depends on whether you want CSRF protection or not

Comment: Are these attacks common?

Comment: That depends on how likely and attractive a target your site and your users are. Check out [Cross-Site Request Forgery on owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing

```
Response.Redirect("rolenotfound");
        return View();
```

to

```
 return PartialView("rolenotfound");
```

this did not hinder me from using the anti forgery token, however the layout is not included in this case but that won't be a problem in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think is that the problem you have is that you are not ending your response after redirect. The difference between `Response.Redirect("rolenotfound");` and `Response.Redirect("rolenotfound", true);` is, that second will abort thread and prevent from executing `return View();`.

I assume, that although redirect is performed, `return View();` will execute and throw `System.Web.HttpException`.

CSRF are pretty common in my opinion(at least if you have an application, which is attractive for attackers) but nobody will tell you whether you need this kind of protection or not - you have to decide on your own.